# how to get IWebHostEnvironment instance in multitenancy class

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

In startup ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, AppTenantMiddleware>(); 
services.AddTransient<ITeamService, TeamService>(provider => MultiTenentDB<TeamService>(provider));
```

In startup Configure:

```
 app.UseMultitenancy<AppTenant>();
```

AppTenant class:

```
public class AppTenant
{
    
    public AppTenant(string orgid,IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // not getting value of env here
        SQL_CON = DEV_CONN;
        MongoDbServer = getDatabseConnectionAsync(orgid);
    }
```

I am unable to get the IHostingEnvironment  value in AppTenant constructor which is called for every request. I need to get DB connection(DEV_CONN/PROD_CONN) based on environment variables to pull tenenant DB connections from developmet DB and production DB

Comment: Why are you writing new code against an [obsolete interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: If you are using .NET version >=3 then try using IHostEnvironment instead

Comment: I need to pull tenant DB connections from Databse based on environment variable in AppTenant class